# indexed field deletion not effecting index size

Tags: solr, solr4

I am using solr 4 for storing my details.
In my collection more than 1cr records is there.
Each record have almost 2000 indexed fields.
Index size of my solr is almost 18GB.

> Some days before i deleted more than  15cr indexed dynamic field by
>   using the following code.

```
data_json = [{"id": 12, "field_to_be_removed": {"set": null}}]

req = urllib2.Request(url="http://stg.solr.freshersworld.com/solr/collection1/update/json'",data=data_json)
req.add_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

fields are  deleted from my records.But its not effected to index size. Index size still 18GB.
Why?
Please give me a solution to reduce my index size..

Answer (score 2):

Delete documents or fields in solr will not change the size of index. You need to optimize the solr. Please refer to: [Do SOLr index size decrease after deleting documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562951/do-solr-index-size-decrease-after-deleting-documents) and also: [How to optimize solr index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954358/how-to-optimize-solr-index)

And Optimize your solr may take very long time.